# Terarria Ore Map Reference

Tags: terraria-console

Does anyone have or know of a decent reference for ore color (and possibly typical depths) on the minimap? I am on a console (no mods); I see a lot of images full screen map discovery (from PCs), but none calling out all the ores (or basic ones... specifically I have no idea what lead/tin/iron/titanium look like on my map) and I get lost running around looking all over the place x_x

Comment: I don't know how this would work on console, if it does at all, but on PC you can hover the cursor over an ore patch on the map to have a tooltip pop up naming what kind of ore it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find one so I made my own. Note I made this on PC so I'm not sure if console has the exact same colors.

[image: Ore minimap colors]

Row 1: copper, iron, silver, gold, demonite, meteorite, hellstone

Row 2: tin, lead, tungsten, platinum, crimtane, chlorophyte

Row 3: cobalt, mythril, adamantium

Row 4: palladium, orichalcum, titanium